# How can I use helm-descbinds to execute a function?

Tags: helm

I am using `helm-descbinds` to help me locate functions and the documentation says it should be possible to execute the function once you select it.

What keys should I use to execute the functions:

The options are

```
Execute the command
Describe the command
Find the command
```

Selecting the command displays info about the command below so I assume it is the same as `Describe the command`. `Find the command` must be superfluous at this state. But how about `Execute the command`?

Comment: Simply hit `RET` to run the first/default action as usual. If not sure, take a look at the mode line, it is shown there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> (`helm-select-action`) to display the actions (and their corresponding key bindings) for a given helm source.

For `helm-descbinds` the default binding for "Execute" is <kbd>F1</kbd>.  For "Describe" and "Find Function", they are <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd> respectively.